# How to download files from tx_news listView?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, tx-news

i'm currently working on a TYPO3 6.2 site using tx_news.

My goal is that a user can **use the listView directly to download a related file**, like it was possible in TT_news with type download.

The problem is in TX_news is only type news, internal page, external page available.
I dont really want to extend news that much to generate a new news type.

---

I got **two possible solutions**:

### Use external page as link to file

> #### Problem:
>
> I dont really want the user to type the external file link
> into these fields, since its a bigger project with many files.

### Use sys_category and link the "more" field to related file

> #### Problem:
>
> I need a hardcoded check in the template files for the "File
> Download Category" UID. What if this changes, or in a year some new
> people need to maintain this.

This is possible with some template like this, but as is said before, this is an ugly hardcoded check in a template file:

```
<f:for each="{newsItem.categories}" as="category" iteration="catIterator">
</f:for>
```

---

Any help is very appreciated, if someone knows a better, cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify: With 'listView' you mean a list of news items?

If so,
You could add a TemplateLayout to display only the URLs of the related files.

Answer (score 0):

tx_news provides the news type "Internal Link", too.
With this type, it is possible to create a direct link to a file (on your webspace), page, folder or email.

[image: TYPO3 v.6.2 BE link wizard]

HTH.